# Writing code for multiple Api versions for those variables and methods which are deleted in newer versions

Tags: android, bookmarks, android-6.0-marshmallow

According to [these changes on Android 6.0](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-bookmark-browser) I am unable to compile my code as this line `Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI` generates cannot resolve symbol error.

I have tried writing code like this

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
            mCur = ctx.getContentResolver().query(Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI,
                    Browser.HISTORY_PROJECTION, null, null, "date DESC");
        }else{
            //TODO code for newer version
        }
```

I am compiling my code with api23 but can not build project, should I lower down to api22 or is there any other way to compile this code using api23.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of Marshmallow, you will be unable to actually use the bookmarks.

From [Android issue tracker #2805](https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=2805#c12):

> Global bookmarks are no longer available.  They haven't really done
>   anything for a long time anyway, since browsers these days generally keep
>   their own internal bookmarks data rather than putting them in the global
>   provider.  Apps using the global provider should likewise switch to
>   maintaining them internally.

However, they will still work on older versions of Android, with the caveat mentioned above. To support older versions of Android while continuing to compile against API 23, you will need to hardcode the old URI.

[Looking at the Lollipop source](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/lollipop-release/core/java/android/provider/Browser.java), the URI is defined as

```
public static final Uri BOOKMARKS_URI = Uri.parse("content://browser/bookmarks");
```

Define this in your own code and proceed as you were before, but make sure that you only use it on API 22 and below.

Comment: Hi @Tanis.7x Thanks for answering. But I need to know how will I be able to compile my code using api23(if possible), so that my code do not crash.

Comment: You can use the `BOOKMARKS_URI` definition I provided to make the code you posted work on everything below API 23. For API 23+ (the else clause in your code), there is no equivalent feature.